am having this error " Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'authReducer' before initialization " in my react app

Uncaught Reference Error: Cannot access 'authReducer' before
initialization

This is the error am having with this Redux-Toolkit as a state manager.
I building small budget e-commerce and its the first time I am using Redux-Toolkit, the problem is how can manage state between reducers in Redux-Toolkit? How can I use the authReducer and the cartReducer in the code?
cartSlice.ts
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import CartProduct from "../../../types/CartProducts";

export interface CartState {
  cart: CartProduct[];
}

interface IncreaseQuantityPayload {
  id: number;
}

interface DecreaseQuantityPayload {
  id: number;
}

interface RemoveItemPayload {
  id: number;
}

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: { cart: [] } as CartState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemInCart = state.cart.find(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );
      if (itemInCart) {
        if (itemInCart.quantity !== undefined) {
          itemInCart.quantity++;
        }
      } else {
        state.cart.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
      }
    },
    increaseQuantity: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<IncreaseQuantityPayload>
    ) => {
      const item = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      if (item && item.quantity !== undefined) {
        item.quantity++;
      }
    },
    decreaseQuantity: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<DecreaseQuantityPayload>
    ) => {
      const item = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      if (item && item.quantity !== undefined && item.quantity > 1) {
        item.quantity--;
      }
    },
    removeItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<RemoveItemPayload>) => {
      state.cart = state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart, increaseQuantity, decreaseQuantity, removeItem } =
  cartSlice.actions;

export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;

authSlice.ts
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import { RootState } from "../store";
import { login, signup, refreshToken } from '../../services/api';

interface AuthState {
  token: string | null;
  refreshToken: string | null;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}

interface UserPayload {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name : string;
}

interface TokenPayload {
  token: string;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  refreshToken: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'),
  isAuthenticated: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const userSignup = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/signup',
  async ({ email, password, name }: UserPayload, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await signup(email, password, name);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error : unknown) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async ({ email, password }: UserPayload, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await login(email, password);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

export const refreshUserToken = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/refresh',
  async ({ token }: TokenPayload, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await refreshToken(token);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error : unknown) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,   
  reducers: {
    logout: (state) => {
      state.token = null;
      state.refreshToken = null;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(userSignup.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(userSignup.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.token = action.payload.token;
        state.refreshToken = action.payload.refreshToken;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.error = null;
        localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', action.payload.refreshToken);
      })
      .addCase(userSignup.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload.message;
      })
      .addCase(userLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(userLogin.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.token = action.payload.token;
        state.refreshToken = action.payload.refreshToken;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.error = null;
        localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', action.payload.refreshToken);
      })
      .addCase(userLogin.rejected, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload.message;
      })
      .addCase(refreshUserToken.fulfilled, (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
        state.token = action.payload.token;
        localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
      });
  },
});

export const { logout } = authSlice.actions;

export const authReducer =  authSlice.reducer;

store.ts
// store   for redux
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { cartReducer }  from "./cart/cartSlice";
import { authReducer } from '../store/auth/authSlice';

// Configure the store
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cartReducer,
    authReducer,
  },
});

store.subscribe(() => {
  const state = store.getState();
  if (state.authReducer.isAuthenticated) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', state.authReducer.token as string);
    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', state.authReducer.refreshToken as string);
  }
});

export default store;

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

Why it giving error:

Uncaught  ReferenceError: Cannot access 'authReducer' before
initialization

After running the code the error still persist.

Looks like you have a circular dependency. Either fix that by not having multiple files import each other, or wrap everything in a function so Javascript gets a chance to import everything before you run any code.

pls can u write it as example,let me see

You have a circular dependency between the authSlice.ts file importing RootState from store.ts and store.ts importing authReducer from authSlice.ts. In other words, authSlice is importing RootState prior to the store being created and RootState defined.
Remove import { RootState } from "../store"; from the authSlice file, it's not used.
